# Android: Make the notification bar as google+

Tags: android, notifications, google-plus, android-notification-bar

Does anyone have an idea or sample code that make the notification bar widget(at the bottom) that is the same as one in **Google+ application** in Android?

Thanks in advance,
Tri.

---

The idea is this widget is the same as notification bar of Android, instead of this is at the bottom and is in customization program (same author Google ;-) )
Below are necessary screenshot for easier.

[image: Main Screen]

[image: We can touch to slide up/down to see all notification items]

[image: And enable to close to let it is back to original state]

Comment: Sorry but I don't follow what you are asking. I've opened the Google+ widget, the Google+ android app, and see no notification bar at the bottom of anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be interested in using the [SlidingDrawer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SlidingDrawer.html).

Here's a great tutorial for getting started with the SlidingDrawer:
http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-view-filpper-and-sliding-drawer/